# ExtJS accordion GridPanels with different height

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have an accordion panel that holds 3 GridPanels. When the page is displayed for the first time, the first two panels are expanded, and the last one collapsed.

Is it possible to make the first GridPanel slightly bigger than the other two?

@lmno :

```
xtype: 'container',
flex: 2,
layout: { type: 'accordion', border: false, multi: true },
items: [
    { xtype: 'myGrid' },
    { xtype: 'pendingGrid' }
]
```

You can set the `multi` property of `Ext.layout.container.Accordion` to `true` to enable multiple accordion items to be open at once.

After that, you can play around with `collapsed` and `collapsible` Grid properties.

Comment: Do you have an example of your accordion with 2 open panels.  I was under the impression that accordion closes the other containers when one is open.

Comment: Yes, I will post it tomorrow, I just left work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this is using the `fill` property for the accordion parent container. Child items can then use the flex property or have their heights specified in another way.

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.layout.container.Accordion-cfg-fill

Answer (score 1):

**this is specifically for when you want to achieve this BUT also have multi:true**

```
 layout: {
                type: 'accordion',
                animate: true,
                multi: true,
                fill: false
            },
            items: [{
                title: 'Panel 1',
                html: 'Panel content!', flex: 2 // or height
            }, {
                title: 'Panel 2',
                html: 'Panel content!', flex: 1
            }, {
                title: 'Panel 3',
                html: 'Panel content!', flex: 1
            }],
```

Took from Sencha forum https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?283045-How-to-have-Grids-under-accordion-panel-with-different-height 
(posted the code anyway in case the link becomes broken in the future.)